# Nonlinear systems near equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, banach-fixed-point

I am trying to understand a method that is used to show well-posedness of nonlinear systems near equilibria.

What I often see is that a system of nonlinear PDEs (usually from physics) is first nondimensionalized, then written as a operator equation. For example , let
$$
F(f_1(t,x),\ldots,f_n(t,x))=
\begin{bmatrix} \text{PDE in }(f_1(t,x),\ldots,f_n(t,x)) \\ \text{PDE in }(f_1(t,x),\ldots,f_n(t,x)) \\ \vdots \\ \text{another PDE in }(f_1(t,x),\ldots,f_n(t,x))\end{bmatrix}=0\tag{*}
$$ 
be such an operator equality with some initial data:
$$
(f_1(t,x),\ldots,f_n(t,x))\vert_{t=0}=(f_{1,0}(x),\ldots,f_{n,0}(x)).
$$

Then, apparently, one needs to find equilibrium solutions to $F$. Therefore, we let 
$$(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))$$
 be an equilibrium solution. Then,
$$
F(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))=0.
$$

In the next step, the following happens (I think it's called perturbation?):

$$
\phi_1={f}_1(x)-\bar{f}_1(x)\\
\phi_2={f}_2(x)-\bar{f}_2(x)\\
\vdots\\
\phi_n={f}_n(x)-\bar{f}_n(x).\\
$$
Apparently, we have now reduced the original problem to finding $(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)$.

Then, we use Taylor series to write $F$ as
$$
F(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)=F(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))+F'(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))[(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)]+R,
$$
where $R$ is the remainder term in an integral form. This is equal to 
$$
F(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)=F'(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))[(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)]+R,
$$
So, finding $(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)$ such that (*) holds is equivalent to solving
$$
F'(\bar{f}_1(x), \bar{f}_2(x),\ldots,\bar{f}_n(x))[(\phi_1, \phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n)]=-R. \tag{1}
$$
It seems that, if one can show optimal regularity of (1), then there exists a solution operator $\Phi$ that solves (1).

Now, the interesting part is that we, for some reason, can use this solution operator to show well-posedness using the Banach fixed-point theorem in a $\epsilon$-ball close to the equilibrium. And this seems to imply that the original nonlinear system (from physics) has a unique solution near equilibria.

> My questions:
>
> 1: If one can show optimal regularity for (1), why can't we then use this solution operator to conclude well-posedness of the original system? Why is the contraction (Banach contraction principle) step necessary? In other words, why is $\Phi$ not a unique solution to the original nonlinear equation?
>
> 2:  Why do we need to stay close to the equilibrium?